# Initialize a constructor that only takes a type of double with TextBox.Text

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a Wilks Calculator with Windows Forms. I have a Constructor:

```
public Calculation(double squat, double bench, double deadlift, double weight)
```

but its parameters are of type double. However, I need the user to input into a TextBox (which is of type string). How do I initialize the constructor with the entries of the textbox?

Comment: parse your `TextBox.Text` to double, use `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`

Comment: My issue is do I do this within the constructor? surely there must be a more elegant solution. Also, doing this in a constructor brings up a System.FormatException Error "Input string was not in a correct format"